# Does a Google + RSS Plugin Exist?

Tags: plugins, google-plus

There are post to Facebook/Twitter plugins but I can't find one for Google Plus.  Does anybody know if such a plugin exists or if there is a better solution?  It would be nice to have content automatically post to a Google Plus page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a plugin to display your Google+ feed in a widget:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-wordpress-widgets/

However, the reverse, of posting from WordPress to a Google+ profile/page is not possible, as the necessary API calls aren't available in Google+. One can read from a profile/page but not write.